# No manifest.json or widget.html file for WAB app

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I want wanted to configure a select widget in my WAB code on my local to have only the selectBy Polygon instead of the out of the box SelectBy square settings. So I created a new WAB app with those settings, downloaded the code, and attempted to copy the new select widget from the downloaded folder. I immediately realized there was no Widget.html file and no manifest.json file. Everything else looked similar in terms of file structure. I also noticed that the Widget.js code looked a lot different (It was no formatted correctly and looked almost minified) than the original select Widget.js file. For example, there was a selectBy parameter in the new code, but nothing in the original code (I thought maybe I could just modify the original). Any suggestions as to what's going on here? The new widget definitely won't add to my app view without those missing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer actually came from a ESRI GeoNet community member, but I am including it here in case someone has a similar problem. Changing the geometry type in the config folder does indeed work:
"
   When downloading an app from AGOL WAB all the code will be minified/uglified. You really did not need to go though all that just to change the SelectBy options avaulable in your widget. just go to your apps folder and then the configs folder and find the select widgets folder and modify the select widgets json manually.
"

```
 "geometryTypes": [
    "POLYGON"
  ],
```